# datatool's \DTLfetch returns last found value instead 'Undefined Value' if entry is not found

Tags: datatool, csv

I want to have some condition of what to do if the key that was provided is not in the db. But \DTLfetch does return a value in case it had found one before. How can I catch all the 'x' in this example?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

% csv file 1
\begin{filecontents*}{abbreviationss.csv}
    term, abbreviation
    Machine Learning, ML
    Artificial Neural Network, ANN
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{abbreviations}{abbreviationss.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item x : \DTLfetch{abbreviations}{term}{x}{abbreviation}
    \item Machine Learning : \DTLfetch{abbreviations}{term}{Machine Learning}{abbreviation}
    \item x : \DTLfetch{abbreviations}{term}{x}{abbreviation}
    \item Artificial Neural Network : \DTLfetch{abbreviations}{term}{Artificial Neural
    Network}{abbreviation}
    \item x : \DTLfetch{abbreviations}{term}{x}{abbreviation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most easy approach is using `\DTLgetvalueforkey` (and evaluating/calling the macro defined by `\DTLgetvalueforkey`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{abbreviationss.csv}
    "term", "abbreviation"
    Machine Learning, ML
    Artificial Neural Network, ANN
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{abbreviations}{abbreviationss.csv}

\newcommand{\getabbreviation}[1]{% 
    #1 : %
    \DTLgetvalueforkey{\scratchmacro}{abbreviation}{abbreviations}{term}{#1}%
    \scratchmacro
    %\scratchmacro will be \@dtlnovalue -> "Undefined Value" if #1 is not found.
    % Alternatively:
    % \DTLifnull{\scratchmacro}{Hey, this is undefined!}{\scratchmacro}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item\getabbreviation{x}   
\item\getabbreviation{Machine Learning}
\item\getabbreviation{x}
\item\getabbreviation{Artificial Neural Network}
\item\getabbreviation{x}
\end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

[Like the approach of Simon Dispa this is based on `\DTLforeach*`:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610005/118714)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{abbreviationss.csv}
    "term", "abbreviation"
    Machine Learning, ML
    Artificial Neural Network, ANN
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{abbreviations}{abbreviationss.csv}

\newif\ifnotfound
\global\notfoundtrue

\newcommand{\getabbreviation}[1]{% 
    #1 : %
    \global\notfoundtrue
    \DTLforeach*[{\equal{\term}{#1}}]{abbreviations}{\abbreviation=abbreviation, \term=term}%
                {\abbreviation\global\notfoundfalse\dtlbreak}%
    \ifnotfound Undefined Value\fi
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item\getabbreviation{x}   
\item\getabbreviation{Machine Learning}
\item\getabbreviation{x}
\item\getabbreviation{Artificial Neural Network}
\item\getabbreviation{x}
\end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

**If the real-life-scenario is not just about some `itemize`-thing but you really need to catch the situation of `\DTLfetch` not finding the `⟨column1 value⟩`:**

With your MWE you get a lot of `` ! Package datatool Error: No row found in database `abbreviations' for column ` 1' matching `x'. ``-errors on the terminal and in the .log-file.

Syntax of `\DTLfetch` is:

```
\DTLfetch{⟨db name⟩}%
         {⟨column1 name⟩}%
         {⟨column1 value⟩}%
         {⟨column2 name⟩}%
```

Section "[6.11.1 Operating on Current Row](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf#subsection.6.11.1)" of the User Manual for datatool bundle version 2.32 says:

> `\dtlgetrowindex{⟨row cs⟩}{⟨db name⟩}{⟨col idx⟩}{⟨value⟩}`
> Similar to `\DTLgetrowindex` but doesn't produce an error if no match is found. You can test the result by using `\ifx⟨row cs⟩\dtlnovalue`.

So you can write a wrapper for `\DTLfetch` which applies

```
\dtlgetrowindex{⟨row cs⟩}%
               {⟨db name⟩}%
               {⟨col idx of column1⟩}%
               {⟨column1 value⟩}%
```

for defining `⟨row cs⟩` and then does:

```
\ifx⟨row cs⟩\dtlnovalue\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
{%
  ⟨ tokens in case ⟨column1 name⟩ does not have a value ⟨column1 value⟩ ⟩%
}{%
  \DTLfetch{⟨db name⟩}{⟨column1 name⟩}{⟨column1 value⟩}{⟨column2 name⟩}%
}%
```

You need the index of column1/of `⟨col idx of column1⟩`.

You can get that via `\dtlcolumnindex{⟨db name⟩}{⟨column1 name⟩}`

In order to have the arguments of `\dtlgetrowindex`—especially `⟨col idx of column1⟩`=`\dtlcolumnindex{⟨db name⟩}{⟨column1 name⟩}`—expanded before carrying out `\dtlgetrowindex`, you can define a scratch-macro via `\protected@edef` where expansion of the command `\dtlgetrowindex` and expansion of the to-be-defined command `⟨row cs⟩` is prevented by prepending `\noexpand`, but the expansion of other arguments of `\dtlgetrowindex` is not prevented, and then call that scratch-macro:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

%\DTLfetchifcolOneValueExists{<db name>}%
%                            {<column1 name>}%
%                            {<column1 value>}%
%                            {<column2 name>}%
%                            {<tokens in case <column1-value> does not exist>}%
%
%   Turn @ into a normal letter so that it can be used as part of the name of a control sequence:
\makeatletter
%   Test if the command \NewDocumentCommand is not available.
%   If so, use traditional \newcommand.  Otherwise use it.
\@ifundefined{NewDocumentCommand}%
{\newcommand\DTLfetchifcolOneValueExists[5]}%
{\NewDocumentCommand\DTLfetchifcolOneValueExists{mmmmm}}%
{%
  % open a local scope:
  \begingroup
  % define the scratch macro
  \protected@edef\@dtl@dogetrowforvalue{%
    \endgroup\noexpand\dtlgetrowindex{\noexpand\dtl@rowidx}{#1}{\dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
  }%
  % Call the scratch-macro:
  \@dtl@dogetrowforvalue
  % Expansion of the scratch-macro yields:
  %   \endgroup %<-after processing \endgroup the local scope is closed and thus the scratch-macro is undefined.
  %   \dtlgetrowindex{\dtl@rowidx}{<expansion of #1>}{<expansion of \dtlcolumnindex{#1}{#2}>}{<expansion of #3>}%
  %   % After processing \dtlgetrowindex the macro \dtl@rowidx is defined.
  \ifx\dtl@rowidx\dtlnovalue\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {#5}{\DTLfetch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}%
\makeatother


% csv file 1
\begin{filecontents*}{abbreviationss.csv}
    term, abbreviation
    Machine Learning, ML
    Artificial Neural Network, ANN
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{abbreviations}{abbreviationss.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item x :
          \DTLfetchifcolOneValueExists{abbreviations}%
                                      {term}%
                                      {x}%
                                      {abbreviation}%
                                      {Column `term' doesn't have a value `x'}
    \item Machine Learning :
          \DTLfetchifcolOneValueExists{abbreviations}%
                                      {term}%
                                      {Machine Learning}%
                                      {abbreviation}%
                                      {Column `term' doesn't have a value `Machine Learning'}
    \item x : 
          \DTLfetchifcolOneValueExists{abbreviations}%
                                      {term}%
                                      {x}%
                                      {abbreviation}%
                                      {\DTLstringnull}
    \item Artificial Neural Network :
          \DTLfetchifcolOneValueExists{abbreviations}%
                                      {term}%
                                      {Artificial Neural Network}%
                                      {abbreviation}%
                                      {Column `term' doesn't have a value `Artificial Neural Network'}
    \item x :
          \DTLfetchifcolOneValueExists{abbreviations}%
                                      {term}%
                                      {x}%
                                      {abbreviation}%
                                      {\dtlnovalue}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to obtain some null-value instead of the phrase "Column `term' doesn't have a value `x' ", you can provide one of the tokens `\DTLstringnull`/`\DTLnumbernull`/`\dtlnovalue` instead. (`\DTLstringnull` yields `NULL`. `\DTLnumbernull` yields `0`. `\dtlnovalue` yields `Undefined Value`.  All three tokens can be used as first argument of `\DTLifnull` etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The command `\itemx` will generate a  new `\item` every time a `term` is found. Otherwise it does nothing.

Output:

[image: A]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{abbreviationss.csv}
    "term", "abbreviation"
    Machine Learning, ML
    Artificial Neural Network, ANN
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{abbreviations}{abbreviationss.csv}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\itemx}[1]{% added <<<<
    \DTLforeach*{abbreviations}{\abbreviation=abbreviation, \term=term}
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{\term}{#1}} 
    {\item \term:   \abbreviation } {}}
            }

\begin{itemize}
    \itemx{x}   
    \itemx{Machine Learning}
    \itemx{x}
    \itemx{Artificial Neural Network}
    \itemx{x}
\end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

**Alternative** (faster and warning)

Using `\DTLassignfirstmatch` and changing `\PackageError` into a `\PackageWarning`

[image: x]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

    
\begin{filecontents*}{abbreviationss2.csv}
    "term", "abbreviation"
    Machine Learning, ML
    Artificial Neural Network, ANN
    Artificial Intelligence, AI
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{abbreviations}{abbreviationss2.csv}

\newcommand{\term}{}
\newcommand{\abbreviation}{}

\makeatletter   
\renewcommand*{\dtl@assignfirstmatch}[4]{%
    \DTLifdbexists{#2}%
    {%
        {%
            \dtlgetrowindex{\dtl@asg@rowidx}{#2}{\dtlcolumnindex{#2}{#3}}{#1}%
            \ifx\dtl@asg@rowidx\dtlnovalue%
            \PackageWarning{datatool}{No match found for \string\DTLassignfirstmatch{#2}{#3}{#1}{#4}}{}%
            \else
            \dtlgetrow{#2}{\dtl@asg@rowidx}%
            \@dtl@assign{#4}{#2}%
            \fi
        }%
    }%
    {%
        \PackageError{datatool}{Data base `#2' doesn't exist}{}%
    }%
}

\makeatother

    \newcommand{\itemx}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\term}{}%
    \renewcommand{\abbreviation}{}%
    \DTLassignfirstmatch{abbreviations}{term}{#1}{\term=term,\abbreviation=abbreviation}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\abbreviation}{}}{\item #1:~(\dtlnovalue)}{\item #1:~(\abbreviation)}%
}

\newcommand{\findx}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\term}{}%
    \renewcommand{\abbreviation}{}%
    \DTLassignfirstmatch{abbreviations}{term}{#1}{\term=term,\abbreviation=abbreviation}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\abbreviation}{}}{~(\dtlnovalue)}{~(\abbreviation)}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \DTLdisplaydb{abbreviations}
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \itemx{x}   
        \itemx{Machine Learning}
        \itemx{x}
        \itemx{Artificial Neural Network}
        \itemx{x}
    \end{itemize}
    
    \bigskip
    
    
    Deep Learning\findx{Deep Learning} is a subset of Artificial Neural Network\findx{Artificial Neural Network},
    which in turn is a subset of Machine Learning\findx{Machine Learning} and
     Artificial Intelligence\findx{Artificial Intelligence}.    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't provide tokens for the "else"-case you can use `\DTLforeach*`'s optional argument: `\DTLforeach*[{\equal{\term}{#1}}]{abbreviations}{\abbreviation=abbreviation, \term=term}{\item#1 : \abbreviation}`